# the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript-security

Just built a ror(ruby on rails) site and all looks fine and function well at home from my internet connection.

when trying to browse from a company internet connection no javascripts are loaded by browser (tested chrome and IE 10)

the errors I get for all JS files:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) https://stamdomain.com/javascripts/translations.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

When trying to download the js file I get a security page message (some security client installed on my machiene)
To further harden our security, we are limiting FILE DOWNLOAD from uncategorized, and certain non-business websites that could potentially house virus, malwares and other cyber threats

Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 14:30:57 GMT
Username: 
Your Source IP: 10.11.11.112
URL: GET https://stamdomain.com/javascripts/translations.js 
Category: Uncategorized URLs
File Type: application/javascript
Reason: BLOCK-TYPE
Web Reputation Score: ns 
Malware Category/Name: 
Appliance: 10.11.123.71

not sure where is the problem..client? server? and if there is a way to bypass it and make website accessible in these kind of networks too.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your company network is filtering out JavaScript on sites that aren't whitelisted (honestly not a bad idea on their part). You'll need to talk to your network administrator to get it unblocked - that said, don't be surprised if they say no.

Comment: Thanks, so no development to be done on my side:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Joe Clay this was a security issue on client pc installed by company